# Как обратиться к виджету на web-странице?

Tags: javascript, iframe, виджет

Есть веб страница с виджетом. Нужно прописать скрипт для действий в этом виджете. Однако при срабатывании скрипта, документ не видит элементы из виджета. Я могу вручную выбрать вкладку с виджетом в консоли (select-services) и вписать туда скрипт, тогда всё будет работать. Возможно ли это сделать программно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`<iframe class="yWidgetIFrame" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" src="https://b592950.yclients.com/?preview_id=240&amp;preview_nonce=52409a8c13&amp;preview=true"></iframe>`

P.S пробовал **document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow**, но доступа к элементам он не дает

Comment: Невозможно ради безопасности